# values from Appengine datastore is not displayed

Tags: google-app-engine

```
This is my first servlet...

public class ServletCheckServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");

    PrintWriter pw=resp.getWriter();
    String s1=req.getParameter("username");
    String s2=req.getParameter("password");

    DatastoreService datastore=DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    Entity employee=new Entity("Employee");

    employee.setProperty("firstname", "Ram");
    employee.setProperty("lastname", "prasad");


    Date hiredate=new Date();
    employee.setProperty("Hiredate", hiredate);
    employee.setProperty("attendedHRtraining",true);
    datastore.put(employee);

    Key employeekey=KeyFactory.createKey("employees", "employee1");
}
}
```

My second servlet is below....

```
public class ValidUserServlet extends HttpServlet{
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse resp){
    PrintWriter pw;
    try {
        pw = resp.getWriter();
        pw.println("Welcome to the second servlet");

        Key employeekey=KeyFactory.createKey("employees", "employee1");

    DatastoreService datastore=DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
        try {
            Entity employee=datastore.get(employeekey);
            String fn=(String) employee.getProperty("firstname");

            pw.println(fn);


        } catch (EntityNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

}
```

But when i run this Application.....the servlet displys...but the values from Appengine  datastore is not displayed...

What is the problem in my programs...how to clear this...is it correct......

Please help me.......

Comment: do some logging to see whether it fetches..use out.println() to see the output

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `Key employeekey=KeyFactory.createKey("employees", "employee1");`

You can use

`Entity employeeEntity = datastore.get(KeyFactory.stringToKey(employee.getId()));`

Since you are using a plain old servlet you can get `employeeId` from request

```
String employeeId = request.getParameter("employeeId");
Entity employeeEntity = datastore.get(KeyFactory.stringToKey(employeeId);
```

You can reference this [source code](http://code.google.com/p/i-cinema/source/browse/trunk/iCinema/src/com/icinema/server/CinemaServiceImpl.java) to further clarify.